# Authentication php mail

Tags: php

I'm using [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/function.mail.php) to send e-mails from PHP. It's working fine, but now I need to use a more secure mail server.

I need to connect with the mail server using the following configuration:

```
smtp: "mail.newserver.com"
port: "25"
timeout: 60
auth: yes
user: name
pass: word
```

How should I change my code below so it works with above configuration?

```
$to = $SendTo;
$headers = "From: <info@---->" . "\r\n" . "X-Mailer: php";
$subject = "Website Contact : " . $uxGlobalLocation;
$body = $Bodycopy;

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    header ('Location: /index.php?option');
    exit();
} else {
    echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually mail function doesn't provide authentication functionality. Your have to use Mail class from Mail Pear package.
See here for an example:
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

Comment: I was looking at the article earlier guess I have to install Pear

Comment: Or you could write a function to connect to smtp yourself, it IS an option.

Answer (score 8):

The builtin [mail()](http://php.net/mail) function does not provide any sort of authentication. You need to use a third-party library that offers SMTP authentication. Popular choices include:

- [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
- [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)
- [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected) *(has not been updated for a while)*

You can also search for Composer packages at [Packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=mail).