# Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port", XAMPP for WIndows XP

Tags: php, email, windows-xp, xampp, localhost

I am running a XAMPP server on Windows XP. Allegedly XAMPP automatically prepares a mail server.

This is the code I am using:

```
$cimzett = 'ledit4@gmail.com';
...
mail($cimzett, $targy, $uzenet, 'From:'.$email);
```

(`$cimzett` means "to", `$targy` is subject, `$uzenet` is message in Hungarian)
but in the browser appling PHP it sends me this message:

I get this error message:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\alien.php on line 50
```

I tried to use `set_ini()` function too, but I got the same message.

Maybe the security properties of XAMPP does not allow  me send an email to gmail.com?

I use PHP Version 5.3.5 and

SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25

are the settings reported by phpinfo();

I suspect the mail server is not working properly. What do you think?

Answer (score 7):

Windows does not by default have an SMTP server installed. XAMPP won't install one for you either. If there IS one installed, then it's not running, because "connection refuse" on port 25 means nothing's there listening for email.

XAMPP will also not disable connections to external mail servers. However, Windows firewalls and/or some ISPs will (my isp does not allow external smtp connections as an anti-spam measure).

Comment: how can I enable ?, how can I install ?, do you have some links ?

Answer (score 1):

May be you should setup mail submitting as external account, your gmail one for example. more info  here: 
[Authentication php mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455469/authentication-php-mail)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to do it anyway in your local machine, try installing IIS and configure the SMTP server from there. Remember this process is only for SMTP, you dont have to change existing installation of Apache and PHP. For more details,here is the link http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e4cf06f5-9a36-474b-ba78-3f287a2b88f2.mspx?mfr=true

After following steps, the mail will be saved as a file in wwwroot directory. You may need to make further research on this, but you can take this solution as a starting point.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You will need an additional SMTP Server Application because Xampp doesn't support it. Download "Post Cast Server" version > 2.  Goto tools -> Settings -> System -> SMTP server 
and set 
Host name as localhost
server port as 25.
And run the application minimized. It will definitely work because it has worked out for me when I was facing the same problem.