# How to supply an authentication method on the forms php?

Tags: php, forms

Problem is next:
On our customer site `mail()` function doesn't work.
`error_reporting(E_ALL)` gives me next

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set().....
```

I need to supply an authentication method on the forms to make `mail()` function work.
I got some details from hosting company.but have no idea how to use them

Server: mail.fortishosting.net

Port: 25

Username / Password

Any Help highly appreciated

```
$senderEmailId = "Reply-To: $email";
$senderEmailId = "From: $email\r\n";
$senderEmailId .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$subject ="New Enquiry from the Adtube website";
// here is captcha validation ....
    if($response['success'] == false){
?>
<script language="javascript">
    alert("Sorry,An Error Occurred.Please Try After Some Time");
    window.history.back();
</script>  
<?php
    }else{
        if (mail($sendToEmail,$subject,$content,$senderEmailId)){
            header("Location:thankyou.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication php mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455469/authentication-php-mail)

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem, but:
On the second lane you're missing a . before = ... actually you're just overwriting the $senderEmailID once. $sendToEmail is defined somewhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455469/authentication-php-mail

Comment: Twinfriends - thank you for pointing to my mistake

Comment: Thanks guys,PHPMailer helped me