# Why does the mail function stop the php script instead of sending the mail?

Tags: php, email, smtp, localhost

I am trying to call the mail function, but whenever I put it in the script,  the page does not load.

I have the following code for my `php.ini` file in XAMPP:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=80
auth_username = XX_MYEMAIL_XX
auth_password = XXXXX_MYPASSWORD_XX
```

I have a 64-bit computer, but an error message said it was missing a sendmail_from, so I gave this variable a value. I have Mercury running from XAMPP, but I don't know if I configured anything that needs to be configured.

I get the following error

> mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 80, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

I used the following php code:

```
<?php     
$header = "From: varunsingh87@yahoo.com";
$to_email = 'VSpoet49@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Testing PHP Mail';
$message = 'This mail is sent using the PHP mail function';
if (mail($to_email, $subject, $message)) {
 echo "<p>Email sent!</p>";
} else {
 echo "<p>Email not sent.</p>";
}
?>
```

Below this is the default html tags.

---

Update

I removed the `sendmail_from` and set the `smtp_port` to 25.

> mail(): Bad Message Return Path i

---

**Related**

- [Warning: Bad Message Return Path (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404390/warning-bad-message-return-path-php)
- [Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25)

Comment: You're not running a mail daemon on your local host.

Comment: @Barmar what exactly is a daemon?

Comment: The error says it cannot connect to the port.  So ensure your mail server (i.e. daemon) runs and listens on port 80.  Kinda weird running SMTP on port 80 though...  80 default to http normally.

Comment: @Nic3500 you are right. I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I never heard for mail server listening on port 80.
I have XAMPP installed too, but with configured with "smpt_port=25".

Second, you have "SMTP=localhost" so in order to send email you must have installed mail server on your machine, for example "Mercury" from XAMPP package.

Third, it can be very tricky to properly send email using "mail()" function (authentication, spam detection...) so best solution is to avoid usage of "mail()" function and use some robust library/component/script for that.

It is good advice by Baranix to learn how to use PhpMailer or [SwiftMailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer) (my favourite) and configure them to target real, well configured mail server on real hosting.

Comment: 1. I updated that

2. I have Mercury running but I don't know if I configured it

3. I understand that, but that doesn't mean the `mail()` function _shouldn't_ work, right?

Comment: Sorry, I never used Mercury. "mail()" function will NOT work if "SMTP" and "smtp_port" settings are incorrect, mail server must be at that location and listenting at that port.

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to use PhpMailer and don't mess with this embarrassing mail function.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial

With this class you will send all messages with and without authorization, with or without tls/ssl and attachments (files, images).

!!! Install smtp server: hmailserver on localhost first !!!

https://www.hmailserver.com/download

And create your domain email mailbox.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Let us learn about the [@](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) symbol, but be warned of a possible fake return status.

People typically try this first though

[Try Catch Block](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: What does this have anything to do with my question?

Comment: Never mind, but this is not what I am looking for at all.

Comment: I know, but I don't use the internal mail function. It's more important that you have code that completes. This function throws an error that wasn't caught. I'll help fix what I can.

Comment: My entire question was about successfully sending the email...